# Add new empty rows to a SAS table with names from another table

Tags: sas

Assume I have table `foo` which contains a (dynamic) list of new rows which I want to add to another table `have`, so that it yields a table `want` looking e.g. like this:

```
x    y   p_14   p_15
1    2   2      99
2    4   7      24
```

Example data for `foo`:

```
id    row_name
14    p_14
15    p_15
```

Example data for `have`:

```
x    y    p    Z  
1    2    14   2
1    2    15   99
1    2    16   59
2    4    14   7
2    4    15   24
2    4    16   58
```

What I have so far is the following which is not yet in macro shape:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select old.*, t1.p_14, t2.p_15 /* choosing non-duplicate rows */
  from (select x, y from have) old
  left join (select x, y, z as p_14 from have where p=14) t1
       on old.x=t1.x and old.y=t1.y
  left join (select x, y, z as p_15 from have where p=15) t2
       on old.x=t2.x and old.y=t2.y
  ;
quit;
```

Ideally, I am aiming for a macro where which takes `foo` as input and automatically creates all the joins from above. Also, the solution should not spit out any warnings in the console. My challenge is how to dynamically choose the correct (non-duplicate) rows.

PS: This is a follow-up question of [Populate SAS macro-variable using a SQL statement within another SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224752/) The important bit is that it is not a full transpose, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can go from HAVE to WANT with PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=p_  ;
  by x y ;
  id p ;
  var z;
run;
```

To limit it to the values of P that occur in FOO you could use a macro variable (as long as the number of observations in FOO is small enough).

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select id into :idlist separated by ' ' from foo ;
quit;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=p_  ;
  where p in (&idlist) ;
  by x y ;
  id p ;
  var z;
run;
```

If the issue is you want variable P_17 to be in the result even if 17 does not appear in HAVE then add a little more complexity.  For example add another data step that will force the creation of the empty variables. You can generate the list of variable names from the list of id's in FOO.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select id , cats('p_',id)
    into :idlist separated by ' '
       , :varlist separated by ' '
  from foo 
  ;
quit;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=p_  ;
  where p in (&idlist) ;
  by x y ;
  id p ;
  var z;
run;

data want ;
   set want (keep=x y);
   array all &varlist ;
   set want ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    x    y    p_14    p_15    p_17

 1     1    2      2      99       .
 2     2    4      7      24       .
```

If the number of values is too large to store in a single macro variable (limit 64K bytes) you could generate the WHERE statement with a data step to a file and use %INCLUDE to add the WHERE statement into the code.

```
filename where temp;
data _null_;
   set foo end=eof;
   file where ;
   if _n_=1 then put 'where p in (' @;
   put id @ ;
   if eof then put ');' ;
run;
proc transpose ... ;
%include where / source2;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use macro program:

```
data have;
input x    y    p    Z;
cards; 
1    2    14   2
1    2    15   99
1    2    16   59
2    4    14   7
2    4    15   24
2    4    16   58
;
data foo;
input id  row_name $;
cards;
14    p_14
15    p_15
;

%macro test(dsn);
proc sql;
   select count(*) into:n trimmed from &dsn;
   select id into: value separated by ' ' from &dsn;
   create table want as
   select distinct a.x,a.y,
   %do i=1 %to &n;
   %let cur=%scan(&value,&i);
   t&i..p_&cur
   %if &i<&n %then ,;
   %else ;
   %end; 
   from have a
   %do i=1 %to &n;
   %let cur=%scan(&value,&i);
   left join have (where=(p=&cur) rename=(z=p_&cur.)) t&i.
   on a.x=t&i..x and a.y=t&i..y
   %end;
   ;
quit;
%mend;

%test(foo);
```